# Using another index structure in Apache Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I would like to use Lucene to write my own search engine. Because I use spatial information, I would like to try some index structures which are more suitable for spatial data. As far as I know there is no alternative structure available in Lucene itself, also LGTE  (Lucene extension for geo-temporal date) seems not to let you access other structures.
Did I just not see other structures or do I have to implement them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct and simple answer to the title of your question, "can you use another index structure" is that you can't -- at least you can't if it would have a different API than Lucene's.  In a nutshell, it is fundamentally a sorted mapping of bytes to DocIds + optionally postings (position offsets for a document plus optionally "payloads" (arbitrary bytes for a posting).

That said, I suppose you could implement a so-called Lucene Codec (new in Lucene 4.x) that has its own extended API and search against a field that assumes your specific Codec.  Codecs are envisioned to have different implementations of Lucene's APIs (e.g. balancing what's in memory vs on-disk, when to cleverly compress/encode vs directly represent data) but not to introduce different API as well.  But I suppose you could.

The context beyond the title of your question is that you want to do this for spatial/temporal because, it appears to me you don't believe that Lucene's index is sufficiently suitable.  I strongly disagree.  There have been great strides in Lucene spatial recently and it has more to go still.  For example many non-relational databases will only let you index point data but Lucene spatial can handle any Spatial4j shape (a dependency) and with JTS (another dependency), that's basically all the typical shapes most people want.  And there are scalable recursive algorithms for matching indexed shapes via Intersects, Within, Contains, and Disjoint  predicates.  I expect some big performance enhancements by end of summer or end of year at the latest.  You may find this very recent post I responded to on the Solr-user list interesting:
http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Multi-dimensional-spatial-search-tt4062515.html#a4062646
So instead I propose that you help me improve the parts of Lucene spatial that need it for whatever system you are building.  Perhaps it already fits the bill.

Comment: Ok, I believe that Lucenes index structure IS effective. But the thing is, it's a project where I want to compare different 'standard' structures together with temporal data, too. So I want to use the Intervall-Tree or R-Tree and its derivates.